# Get records count from sql server table in the most optimized way

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization, count

I want to get the records count from an sql server table with more than 100 000 records, I'm using the `Count(Id)` method, but it take a lot of time (about 7 to 8 secondes), is there any way to make it faster, knowing that I am using a where clause in my `Select`

```
SELECT Count(StudentID) WHERE Type = 1 AND Name Like %Sid%
```

I found that we can use the following method

```
SELECT rows FROM sysindexes 
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.StudentID') AND indid < 2
```

But unfortunately I can not add my WHERE clause to this. Is there away to do it ?

My Index definition for the Type field : **(Non unique, non cluster)**

Comment: @SidAhmed Could you add that index definition to the question?

Comment: If your studentID numbers count up (1..Max), you could jerry-rig it and just select max. Although I'd suggest heavily against it.

Comment: Or the execution plan

Comment: @Elias : I can not use Max because a student may be deleted.

Comment: It was a relatively silly suggestion, but could be legitimate nonetheless.

Comment: create an indexed view with the counts by type.  that way the heavy lifting is done to get the totals before the select to get the current count occurs.

Comment: How many rows are in the table as a whole; and how many match the `Type=1` clause?

Comment: more than 100 000 rows, and the result may be more than 10 000, note : the where clause may be change to add a filter on a nvarchar field.

Comment: 7-8 seconds to count some subset of 100,000 records doesn't sound right. Is the server busy? Does it only run slow when you add in the additional `nvarchar` filter? How much data is stored in each record (how 'long' are they)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `sysindexes.rows` will not necessarily provide an exact answer and, as you mention, you can't filter to a subset of the records.

If you need to know the exact number of records, you must use `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(<column_name>)` (depending on whether you want NULLS to count or not).

In your case, if you have an index that has the column `Type` as its first column, the query optimizer should use that index to speed up the count automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to get your count with conditions is using `COUNT()`.

If you have a valid index on `Type` (that means, it's the first column of an index), it's better to count that very field or `*` so that the database does not need to fetch `StudentID` to count it. In other words;

```
SELECT COUNT(Type) FROM Students WHERE Type=1
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Students WHERE Type=1
```

Note that this will change the meaning of the query slightly, if StudentID can be null, the row would not have been counted before, but will now.